# Expand helm template variables to lookup named-template/sub-template in _helpers.tpl

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

Trying to do the following in helm template but it's not expanding `$key` and giving an error cannot find `template $key .`

Is this even possible?

values.yaml

```yaml
app:
  env:
  - AAAA
```

_helpers.tpl

```yaml
{{- define "AAAA" }}
  {{- printf "BBBB" }}
{{- end }}
```

deployment.yaml

```yaml
...
container:
- name: xxxx
  env:
  {{- range $key := .Values.app.env }}
  - name: {{ $key }}
    value: {{ template "$key" . }} 
  {{ end }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like using `include` instead of `template` works

values.yaml

```yaml
app:
  env:
  - AAAA
```

_helpers.tpl

```yaml
{{- define "AAAA" }}
  {{- printf "BBBB" }}
{{- end }}
```

deployment.yaml

```yaml
...
container:
- name: xxxx
  env:
  {{- range $key := .Values.app.env }}
  - name: {{ $key }}
    value: {{ include $key . }} 
  {{ end }}
```